# looking for source code of from gen_nn_ops in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, deconvolution

I am new to tensorflow for deep learning and interested in deconvolution (convolution transpose) operation in tensorflow. I need to take a look at the source code for operating deconvolution. The function is I guess [conv2d_transpose() in nn_ops.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L1007).

However, in the function it calls another function called `gen_nn_ops.conv2d_backprop_input()`. I need to take a look at what is inside this function, but I am unable to find it in the repository. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 53):

You can't find this source because the source is automatically generated by bazel. If you build from source, you'll see this file inside `bazel-genfiles`. It's also present in your local distribution which you can find using `inspect` module. The file contains automatically generated Python wrappers to underlying C++ implementations, so it basically consists of a bunch of 1-line functions. A shortcut to find underlying C++ implementation of such generated Python op is to convert snake case to camel case, ie `conv2d_backprop_input` -> `Conv2dBackpropInput`

```
# figure out where gen_nn_ops is
print(tf.nn.conv2d_transpose.__globals__['gen_nn_ops'])

from tensorflow.python.ops import gen_nn_ops
import inspect
inspect.getsourcefile('gen_nn_ops.conv2d_backprop_input')
'/Users/yaroslav/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py'
```

If you cared to find out how this file really came about, you could follow the trail of bazel dependencies in `BUILD` files. It to find Bazel target that generated it from tensorflow source tree:

```
fullname=$(bazel query tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py)
bazel query "attr('srcs', $fullname, ${fullname//:*/}:*)"

//tensorflow/python:nn_ops_gen
```

So now going to `BUILD` file inside `tensorflow/python` you see that this is a target of type `tf_gen_op_wrapper_private_py` which is defined [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/754048a0453a04a761e112ae5d99c149eb9910dd/tensorflow/python/build_defs.bzl) and calls `gen_op_wrapper_py` from `tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl` which looks like this

```
def tf_gen_op_wrapper_py(name, out=None, hidden=None, visibility=None, deps=[],
....
      native.cc_binary(
      name = tool_name,
```

This `native.cc_binary` construct is a way to have Bazel target that represents execution of an arbitrary command. In this case it calls `tool_name` with some arguments. With a couple more steps you can find that "tool" here is compiled from [framework/python_op_gen_main.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/BUILD#L273)

The reason for this complication is that TensorFlow was designed to be language agnostic. So in ideal world you would have each op described in [ops.pbtxt](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/294442996b2aeff00b1bfdc7e7169f7cb35bbf3d/tensorflow/core/ops/ops.pbtxt), and then each op would have one implementation per hardware type using `REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER`, so all implementations would be done in C++/CUDA/Assembly and become automatically available to all language front-ends. There would be an equivalent translator op like "python_op_gen_main" for every language and all client library code would be automatically generated. However, because Python is so dominant, there was pressure to add features on the Python side. So now there are two kinds of ops -- pure TensorFlow ops seen in files like `gen_nn_ops.py`, and Python-only ops in files like `nn_ops.py` which typically wrap ops automatically generated files `gen_nn_ops.py` but add extra features/syntax sugar. Also, originally all names were camel-case, but it was decided that public facing release should be PEP compliant with more common Python syntax, so this is a reason for camel-case/snake-case mismatch between C++/Python interfaces of same op

Comment: Hi, when I typed  inspect.getsourcefile('gen_nn_ops.conv2d_backprop_input'), I got TypeError: 'gen_nn_ops.conv2d_backprop_input' is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object

Comment: My tf version is '1.2.1'. How should I go around this?

Comment: I guess you are missing an import

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, TensorFlow code is not easy to read :(

To make things fast, the python code has to interleave C++ code, which also uses indirect dependencies.

`gen_X` functions are generated from their C++ code; to find it, you need to search for `Conv2dBackpropInput`.

You can find the registration of the kernel op in [ops/nn_ops.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/86f5ab7474825da756838b34e1b4eac93f5fc68a/tensorflow/core/ops/nn_ops.cc#L548) and concrete implementation in [kernels/conv_grad_input_ops.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5a566a7701381a5cf7f70fce397759483764e482/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_grad_input_ops.cc#L98).

Answer (score 3):

This is generated file when you build Tensorflow.
After you build Tensorflow source, you should see a symbolic link file named "**bazel-genfiles**" at tensorflow root directory, and go to the location it points, and then you can find it at **tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py**

Answer (score -1):

I use tensor flow TF2, on google colab:

```
import inspect
inspect.getsourcefile(gen_nn_ops.conv2d_backprop_input)
'/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py'
```