# Can't find "gen_training_ops" in the tensorflow GitHub

Tags: python, optimization, tensorflow, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on a new optimizer, and I managed to work out most of the process. Only thing I'm stuck on currently is finding `gen_training_ops`.

Apparently this file is crucial, because in both implementations of Gradient Descent, and Adagrad optimizers they use functions that are imported out of a wrapper file for `gen_training_ops` (`training_ops.py` in the `python/training` folder).
I can't find this file anywhere, so I suppose I don't understand something and search in the wrong place. Where can I find it? (Or specifically the implementations of `apply_adagrad` and `apply_gradient_descent`)

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The file seems to be generated https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/BUILD#L912

Comment: You can find it on your local disk by using `inspect.getsourcefile`, some more background -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/41149557/419116

Comment: @Iluha Bratan, any update on this? Did the comments / answer help?

Answer (score 1):

The file will be generated when you build TensorFlow from source. It is marked as `out` in this file,

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/BUILD#L912

Answer (score 1):

If you find it, youll realize it just jumps to pyhon/framework, where the actual update is just an assign operation and then gets grouped