# Getting Protobuf Message for every TensorFlow Operation

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

From [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/language_bindings/),

There are a few ways to get a list of the OpDefs for the registered ops:

> - TF_GetAllOpList in the C API retrieves all registered OpDef protocol    messages. This can be used to write the generator in the
>     client    language. This requires that the client language have
>     protocol buffer    support in order to interpret the OpDef messages.
> - The C++ function    OpRegistry::Global()->GetRegisteredOps() returns the same list of all    registered OpDefs (defined in
>     [tensorflow/core/framework/op.h]). This    can be used to write the
>     generator in C++ (particularly useful for    languages that do not
>     have protocol buffer support).
> - The    ASCII-serialized version of that list is periodically checked in to    [tensorflow/core/ops/ops.pbtxt] by an automated
>     process.

But alas, I want to do this in Python like,

```
import tensorflow as tf
from google.protobuf import json_format
json_string = json_format.MessageToJson(tf.GetAllOpsList())
```

I want a way to get the Protobuf message for every operation in Tensorflow so that I can dump it as JSON via

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in `ops.txt`. Here's an example of listing all `OpDef` messages for ops that produce strings outputs.

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.core.framework import op_def_pb2
from google.protobuf import text_format

def get_op_types(op):
    for attr in op.attr:
        if attr.type != 'type':
            continue
        return list(attr.allowed_values.list.type)
    return []

# directory where you did "git clone"
tensorflow_git_base = "/Users/yaroslav/tensorflow.git"
ops_file = tensorflow_git_base+"/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops/ops.pbtxt"
ops = op_def_pb2.OpList()
text_format.Merge(open(ops_file).read(), ops)

for op in ops.op:
    # get templated string types
    if tf.string in get_op_types(op):
        print(op.name, op.summary)
    #for arg in op.input_arg:
    for arg in op.output_arg:
        if arg.type == tf.string:
            print(op.name, op.summary)
            break
```

** Added **
If you want to be sensitive to new ops being added you could reverse engineer how current Python wrappers do it. For instance, consider `gen_array_ops.py` file. It has the following snippet

```
def _InitOpDefLibrary():
  op_list = _op_def_pb2.OpList()
  _text_format.Merge(_InitOpDefLibrary.op_list_ascii, op_list)
  _op_def_registry.register_op_list(op_list)
  op_def_lib = _op_def_library.OpDefLibrary()
  op_def_lib.add_op_list(op_list)
  return op_def_lib


_InitOpDefLibrary.op_list_ascii = """op {
  name: "BatchMatrixBandPart"
  input_arg {
    name: "input"
    type_attr: "T"
  }
  input_arg {
    name: "num_lower"
    type: DT_INT64
  }
  input_arg {
    name: "num_upper"
    type: DT_INT64
  }
  output_arg {
    name: "band"
    type_attr: "T"
  }
  attr {
    name: "T"
    type: "type"
  }
  deprecation {
    version: 14
    explanation: "Use MatrixBandPart"
  }
}
```

So those messages protobufs are generated from underlying C code during generation of `gen_array_ops`. For tracking down how they were generated, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41149557/419116

Comment: I would prefer a Python way so I can add custom operations and get the Protobuf out from those

Comment: Added extra info. You could either regenerate "ops.txt" by calling the same generation script as done during gen_*_ops.py generation, or find underlying C functionality and add some swig wrappers

Comment: Thanks! Almost there. I don't care about ascii, but I need JSON. So I changed it to `from google.protobuf import json_format` and discovered that  `json_format.MessageToJson(gen_array_ops._InitOpDefLibrary()._ops['Const'].op_def)` almost gives me what I want. This is just the metaInfoDef, but I need the graphDef block too

Comment: I got a bit further. Still stuck. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42168977/tensorflow-manual-construction-of-graphdef