# Check if node is an operation or a tensor in Tensorflow Graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

Using `names = [n.name for n in graph.as_graph_def().node]` I can get all the node names in the graph.

For instance, say this prints:

```
['model/classifier/dense/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/shape',
'model/classifier/dense/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/min',
'model/classifier/dense/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/max',
'model/classifier/dense/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform',
'model/classifier/dense/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/sub',
'model/classifier/dense/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/mul',
'model/classifier/dense/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform',
'model/classifier/dense/kernel',
'model/classifier/dense/kernel/Assign',
'model/classifier/dense/kernel/read',
'model/classifier/dense/bias/Initializer/zeros/shape_as_tensor',
'model/classifier/dense/bias/Initializer/zeros/Const',
'model/classifier/dense/bias/Initializer/zeros',
'model/classifier/dense/bias',
'model/classifier/dense/bias/Assign',
'model/classifier/dense/bias/read',
'model/classifier/dense/MatMul',
'model/classifier/dense/BiasAdd']
```

How can I select only the operations or only the tensors?

I'm aware of the following workarounds, which will work in specific situations but are not general enough and would not scale to a large graph:

- string manipulations from the above names

  - for instance to get `model/classifier/dense/kernel`:

    ```
    tensor = [graph.get_tensor_by_name(n + ":0") 
        for n in names if 'classifier' in n and
        'kernel' in name and 
        not n.split('kernel')[-1]
    ][0]
    ```
  - As you can imagine this may be very error prone and is very tensor specific
- `try/except` I could get the tensors which are outputs of these operation with:

  ```
  tensors = []
  for name in names:
      try:
          tensors.append(graph.get_tensor_by_name(name + ":0"))
      except KeyError:
          pass
  ```

  - But again this is but a workaround and does not solve the selection problem: what if I just want the `kernel` Tensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the answer. It lied mainly in that what I was really looking for are *Variables* not just regular Tensors.

Therefore it's as easy as:

```
with graph.as_default():
    kernel = [v for v in tf.global_variables()
        if 'optimization' not in v.name and
        'classifier' in v.name
        and 'kernel' in v.name
    ][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want a better feel of operations and nodes, try running tensorboard.
You can write summary files with `tf.summary.FileWriter("folder_name", sess.graph)`.

My tensorflow knowledge is limited but I think that tensor names and operator names are almost the same. An operator can have multiple outputs, and each of these outputs is called a tensor. The tensor name is therefore just `operator_name:output_index`, the `output_index` is often `0`, since most operators have a single output. 
So give running `sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("model/classifier/dense/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/mul:0")` a chance. I'm not sure if having such long names is practical though.

Sorry if the provided information is not 100% correct, I'm just a beginner.

Comment: You are right, it partially answers my question (therefore upvoted but not accepted). But my issue is also that some may have no output at all, such as an initializing op. The workaround would be to try/except KeyError but it sounds like something better should exist.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the isinstance(item, class) and compare the nodes with the tf.Operation class like so `[n.name for n in graph.as_graph_def().node if isinstance(n, tf.Operation)]`

Comment: No it does not work, returns empty list as nodes won't be either (`tf.Operation` nor `tf.Tensor`)

Comment: can you check their \_\_class\_\_?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your question, maybe this can be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42168977/tensorflow-manual-construction-of-graphdef