# Softmax Cross Entropy implementation in Tensorflow Github Source Code

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel, softmax, cross-entropy

I am trying to implement a Softmax Cross-Entropy loss in python. So, I was looking at the implementation of Softmax Cross-Entropy loss in the GitHub Tensorflow repository. I am trying to understand it but I run into a loop of three functions and I don't understand which line of code in the function is computing the Loss?

The function `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels, logits, axis=-1, name=None)` returns the function  `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2_helper(labels=labels, logits=logits, axis=axis, name=name)` , which in turn returns `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(precise_logits, labels, name=name)`.

Now the function `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(precise_logits, labels, name=name)` returns the function `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels, logits, axis=-1, name=None)`.

This makes me fall in a loop of functions without knowing explicitly where the code for computing the `cost` for Softmax function is. Can anyone point out where the code for Softmax Cross-Entropy is Implemented in Tensorflow GitHub Repository?

The link of the GitHub repository that I am referencing is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.1.0/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L3107-L3165). It contains the definitions of the above three functions.

If in case the code for `cost` requires lots of functions which is cumbersome to understand, could you explain the lines of code as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you follow the call stack for this function, you eventually find [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8fe9e086d7193f0bfe55a2fe5cbe3c191fc522aa/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L3542):

```py
cost, unused_backprop = gen_nn_ops.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
      precise_logits, labels, name=name)
```

Whenever you see a reference to a `gen_` module, it means it's an automatically generated python wrapper over the C++ code - that's why you cannot find by simply looking up the function and following call stack.

C++ source code can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c903b4607821a03c36c17b0befa2535c7dd0e066/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/softmax_op.cc).

How `gen_nn_ops` is created is nicely described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41147734/looking-for-source-code-of-from-gen-nn-ops-in-tensorflow).

Comment: Thanks Lukasz for the answer. I was wondering if I can get in touch with you to get some help regarding a Deep Learning Model that I am building from scratch, without using any framework.

Comment: @AmarParajuli Sure. Contact details are on my profile and GitHub, you can easily look me up.