# What exactly is Keras's CategoricalCrossEntropy doing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am porting a keras model over to `torch` and I'm having trouble replicating the exact behavior of keras/tensorflow's `'categorical_crossentropy'` after a softmax layer.  I have some workarounds for this problem, so I'm only interested in understanding what *exactly* tensorflow calculates when calculating categorical cross entropy.

As a toy problem, I set up labels and predicted vectors

```py
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
>>> import numpy as np


>>> true = np.array([[0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0]])
>>> pred = np.array([[0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0]])
```

And calculate the Categorical Cross Entropy with:

```py
>>> loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
>>> print(loss(pred, true).eval(session=K.get_session()))
8.05904769897461
```

This differs from the analytical result

```py
>>> loss_analytical = -1*K.sum(true*K.log(pred))/pred.shape[0]
>>> print(loss_analytical.eval(session=K.get_session()))
nan
```

I dug into the source code for keras/tf's cross entropy (see [Softmax Cross Entropy implementation in Tensorflow Github Source Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61558769/softmax-cross-entropy-implementation-in-tensorflow-github-source-code)) and found the c function at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c903b4607821a03c36c17b0befa2535c7dd0e066/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/softmax_op.cc line 116.  In that function, there is a comment:

```c
// sum(-labels *
// ((logits - max_logits) - log(sum(exp(logits - max_logits)))))
// along classes
// (The subtraction broadcasts along the batch dimension.)
```

And implementing that, I tried:

```py
>>> max_logits = K.max(pred, axis=0)
>>> max_logits = max_logits
>>> xent = K.sum(-true * ((pred - max_logits) - K.log(K.sum(K.exp(pred - max_logits)))))/pred.shape[0]

>>> print(xent.eval(session=K.get_session()))
1.3862943611198906
```

I also tried to print the trace for `xent.eval(session=K.get_session())`, but the trace is ~95000  lines long.  So it begs the question: what exactly is keras/tf doing when calculating `'categorical_crossentropy'`? It makes sense that it doesn't return `nan`, that would cause training issues, but where does 8 come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are using hard 0s and 1s in your predictions. This leads to `nan` in your calculation since `log(0)` is undefined (or infinite).

What is not really documented is that the Keras cross-entropy automatically "safeguards" against this by clipping the values to be inside the range `[eps, 1-eps]`. This means that, in your example, Keras gives you a different result because it flat out replaces the predictions by other values.

If you replace your predictions by soft values, you should be able to reproduce the results. This makes sense anyway, since your networks will usually return such values via a softmax activation; hard 0/1 only happens in the case of numerical underflow.

If you want to check this for yourself, the clipping happens [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.1/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L4707). This function is eventually called by the `CategoricalCrossentropy` function. `epsilon` is defined elsewhere, but it seems to be `0.0000001` -- try your manual calculation with `pred = np.clip(pred, 0.0000001, 1-0.0000001)` and you should see the result `8.059047875479163`.

Comment: Great! I knew the discrepancy was in how Keras was nan guarding, and you found it. I was able to reproduce with Keras and with torch.clamp.  Interestingly, this uses the analytical calculation (sum(-true * log(pred))/batch_size), not the log(sum(exp described in Keras's `softmax_op.cc`.

Answer (score 9):

Here are some things that I noticed in your code.

First, your predictions show two data instances, `[0.0, 1.0]` and `[0.0, 1.0]`.

```py
pred = np.array([[0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0]])
```

They should indicate probabilities, but the values after softmax  typically are not exactly 0.0 and 1.0. Try 0.01 and 0.99 instead.

Second, the [arguments to the CateogoricalCrossEntropy() call](https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#categoricalcrossentropy-class) should be `true, pred`, not `pred, true`.

So this is what I get:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

true = np.array([[0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0]])
pred = np.array([[0.01, 0.99], [0.01, 0.99]])

loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
print(loss(true, pred).numpy())
# 2.307610273361206
```

For completeness, let's try what you did, using `pred, true`:

```py
print(loss(pred, true).numpy())
# 8.05904769897461
```

That's where your mysterious 8.05 came from.

Is my answer `2.307610273361206` correct? Let's compute the loss by hand. Following the explanation in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39499486/4561314), we can compute the loss of each of the two data instances and then compute their average.

```
loss1 = -(0.0 * np.log(0.01) + 1.0 * np.log(0.99))
print(loss1) # 0.01005033585350145

loss2 = -(1.0 * np.log(0.01) + 0.0 * np.log(0.99))
print(loss2) # 4.605170185988091

# Total loss is the average of the per-instance losses.
loss = (loss1 + loss2) / 2
print(loss) # 2.307610260920796
```

So it looks like `CategoricalCrossEntropy()` is producing the right answer.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I agree that most softmax outputs are not _exactly_ zero, but the training in my torch ported code often ends up with a loss of `nan`, which I believe is occurring because one of the predictions is zero.  It looks like there is a clipping applied in keras (by epsilon, as in @xdurch0's answer).