# tensorflow - does nn.softmax takes measures to prevent exp(x) from becoming +inf

Tags: tensorflow

While calculating softmax, exp(x) may become inf causing suftmax returning NaN. I saw a way to prevent.

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# exp(x-c) to prevent the infinite exp(x) for a large value x, with c = max(x).
# keepdims=True to be able to broadcast.
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C = np.max(X, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
exp = np.exp(X - C)
P = np.divide(exp, np.sum(exp, axis=-1, keepdims=True), out=out)
```

Do [tf.nn.softmax](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax) and [tf.keras.activations.softmax](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/activations/softmax) take similar/same measures internally or do I need to make sure `x` will not cause it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, They do. For `keras` activation, check the source code [keras.activations.softmax](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/keras/activations.py#L44-L87):

```
...
e = math_ops.exp(x - math_ops.reduce_max(x, axis=axis, keepdims=True))
s = math_ops.reduce_sum(e, axis=axis, keepdims=True)
output = e / s
...
```

And I believe `tf.nn.softmax` also do the same. Though I can't confirm that because of `from tensorflow.python.ops import gen_nn_ops` import, [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41147734/looking-for-source-code-of-from-gen-nn-ops-in-tensorflow). If you follow the source code, [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L3709-L3734), it passes `gen_nn_ops.softmax` operation to [def _wrap_2d_function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/85c8b2a817f95a3e979ecd1ed95bff1dc1335cff/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L3578).